# Using *ngIf to Handle Displaying Elements Only AFTER Data Has Loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some pagination ui that is currently loading before my data arrives in my Angular 2 app. This creates an unwanted visual effect where the pagination ui components start at the top of the page and then move to the bottom once the data populates. I would like to handle this by wrapping the pagination div with an *ngIf statement, so the pagination components won't load before the data is there.

The data is being stored in a "records" variable, and is being iterated over and passed through a paginate pipe in the view like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 15, currentPage: page, totalItems: customerCount }">
```

The div with the pagination ui looks like this:

```
        <div *ngIf="" class="pagination">
            <pagination-controls class="paginator" (pageChange)="page = $event" id="customers"
                    maxSize="15"
                    directionLinks="true"
                    autoHide="true">
            </pagination-controls>
        </div>
```

You can see above where I'd like to place the *ngIf. My question is, what can I pass to the *ngIf for evaluation here? I tried using *ngIf="records", but that didn't work.

Comment: `but that didn't work.` <= so what did happened exactly. It might help more if you showed us the code in the component, specifically how and where `records` is being set (*if there are multiple places show them all*)

Comment: try `!!records && records.length>0`

Comment: Bill, right on! That did it. If you want to list it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, even just "records.length" alone worked. Which is weird, because I could have sworn I tried that, because that was my initial thought as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!!records && records.length>0`. Take note that `!!records` will prevent the null-error if your records variable is null... if you are certain that the variable is always initialized as an array to begin with, you can omit !!records